# PrimeFaces confirmDialog won't show after changing language

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I have a form with a datatable inside it . In one of the columns is a button to delete that row. That button has a primefaces confirm dialog attached to it.

```
<h:form id="form" style="text-align: -webkit-center">
            <p:dataTable id="preferenceConfigs" var="preferenceConfig"
                         value="#{preferenceManagementBackingBean.preferenceConfigs}">
                <p:column style="width:6rem; text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton update=":form"
                                     title="#{msgs['common.delete.userpreference.button']}"
                                     icon="fa fa-trash"
                                     action="#{preferenceManagementBackingBean.invalidatePreferenceConfig(preferenceConfig)}">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="#{msgs['common.dialog.preference.config.warning']}"
                                   icon="fa fa-exclamation-circle" escape="false"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
            </p:dataTable>

            <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" style="text-align-last: center">
                <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['common.dialog.confirm.yes']}" type="button"
                                 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="fa fa-check"/>
                <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['common.dialog.confirm.no']}" type="button"
                                 styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="fa fa-times"/>
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>
```

Everything works fine until I change the language on the page through a commandLink. They are located in a masterLayout file above this one:

```
<h:form id="generalSettingsForm">
                            <ul id="language">
                                <li><h:commandLink
                                        action="#{languageSessionBean.changeLanguage('en')}" value="EN"
                                        class="blgm_lSwitch" id="EN"/></li>
                                <li><h:commandLink
                                        action="#{languageSessionBean.changeLanguage('nl')}" value="NL"
                                        class="blgm_lSwitch" id="NL"/></li>
                                <li><h:commandLink
                                        action="#{languageSessionBean.changeLanguage('fr')}" value="FR"
                                        class="blgm_lSwitch" id="FR"/></li>
                            </ul>
                        </h:form>
```

```
    public void changeLanguage(String language) {
        locale = new Locale(language);
        findCurrentFacesContext().getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
    }
```

This refreshes the page and displays the correct language. However pressing the remove button now automatically performs the action without any sign of the confirmation dialog. Only if I open another dialog (that is present in the JSF page) and return, will the confirmation shows its face again...

The dev console gives me the following error:

```
VM1391 components.js.xhtml:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at c.show (VM1391 components.js.xhtml:13)
    at c.showMessage (VM1391 components.js.xhtml:13)
    at Object.confirm (VM1391 components.js.xhtml:1)
    at Object.confirm (VM1390 core.js.xhtml:1)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (preferenceManagement.xhtml:58)
```

Any insight?

Comment: Where do you have that commandLink?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the commandlinke. It's located in the "master" JSF page

Comment: [mcve].... Always....

Comment: I've found "the solution" below. it also has a reproducer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling, it seems to be an issue with primefaces 6.2 with the following behaviour:

> confirmDialog does not show, an error is logged on console (TypeError:
>   this.jqEl is undefined)

This was fixed in 6.2.2. I cannot test this myself since all minor releases are for paying users only. As a workaround, I'll try a custom dialog. You can probably also use primefaces 7.0

[official github with reproducer](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3498)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to put the `p:confirmDialog` out of the form? Something like this:

```
<p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" style="text-align-last: center">
    <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['common.dialog.confirm.yes']}" type="button"
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="fa fa-check"/>
    <p:commandButton value="#{msgs['common.dialog.confirm.no']}" type="button"
                     styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="fa fa-times"/>
</p:confirmDialog>

<h:form id="form" style="text-align: -webkit-center">
    <p:dataTable id="preferenceConfigs" var="preferenceConfig"
        value="#{preferenceManagementBackingBean.preferenceConfigs}">
        <p:column style="width:6rem; text-align: center">
            <p:commandButton update=":form" icon="fa fa-trash"
                title="#{msgs['common.delete.userpreference.button']}"
                action="#{preferenceManagementBackingBean.invalidatePreferenceConfig(preferenceConfig)}">
                <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="#{msgs['common.dialog.preference.config.warning']}"
                           icon="fa fa-exclamation-circle" escape="false"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Comment: the issue remains

Comment: Could you try this?

Comment: Don't chameleonize answers. If you want to propose a new answer, create a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that confirmDialog doesn't play well with ajax updating.

Normally a language change means that all the parts of the page must be updated, so there is no benefit in using partial updating.

The easy way to solve it is to set ajax to false on your commandLinks:

```
<h:commandLink action="#{languageSessionBean.changeLanguage('fr')}" 
               value="FR" class="blgm_lSwitch" id="FR" ajax="false" />
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't change the behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Using the version primefaces 6.2 the same thing happened to me, then searching hard I found this solution that worked perfectly, I hope it helps someone, in the web xml add:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>primefaces.MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM</param-name>
   <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```